# Mezzanine MS SQL server 2012 Integration

Tags: sql-server, django, python-2.7, sql-server-2012, mezzanine

I'm trying to install mezzanine but my database specification is to use MS SQL server. Anybody knows how to set the configuration to install mezzanine and start a project with MS SQL server 2012.

Settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        # Add "postgresql_psycopg2", "mysql", "sqlite3" or "oracle".
        "ENGINE": "django.db.sqlserver_ado.",
        # DB name or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        "NAME": "",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "USER": "",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "PASSWORD": "",
        # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        "HOST": "",
        # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        "PORT": "",
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that is  a supported DB? The list of options says "postgresql_psycopg2", "mysql", "sqlite3" **or** "oracle"

Comment: There is third party support for SQL Server: are you hosting on Linux (if so, what flavor?) or Windows Server?

Comment: @Brad - I'm trying to host on windows server and i have a SQL server. I have requirements to pull reports from the SQL server database and show in my mezzanine powered site.

Comment: @FlipperPA I'm hosting on windows, i think i should check for the third party support for SQL Server.

Comment: You're going to want to look into using pyodbc and django-pyodbc-azure with the Windows native SQL Server ODBC drivers, in that case! Good luck. pyodbc: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc django-pyodbc-azure: https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure